# Angularjs directive require is not finding the parent directive controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, directive

When I require a controller in a directive, I am getting error saying that, not able to find the controller. 
Please see the code with the issue below. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/NzmQPA?p=preview

Can someone please have a look at it?

Thanks

Comment: You can only require controller if they have parent-child relationship. See updated plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/iLfc3a?p=preview

Comment: @KhanhTO: Thanks for that. So, if I want a communication between two sibling directives, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a service to communicate between them.  Exactly how/what you do depends on your exact needs (there's not enough info in your post).

Side note, I changed your click handler to an ng-click.

Here's an example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/I2TvvV?p=preview

```
<div search-result-filter></div>
<div search-result-header ng-click="doClick()"></div>

angular.module('mymodule', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.test = "main angular is working";
    }
  ]).controller('searchResultFilterController', ['$scope', 'myService',
    function($scope, myService) {
      //do something with 'myService'
    }
  ])
  .directive('searchResultFilter', [
    function() {
      return {
        replace: true,
        controller: 'searchResultFilterController',
        template: '<h1>this is the first directive</h1>'
      };
    }
  ])
  .directive('searchResultHeader', ['myService',
    function(myService) {
      return {
        replace: true,
        template: '<button>clickme</button>',
        link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
          $scope.doClick = function() {
            myService.someFn();
          };
        }
      };
    }
  ])
  .service('myService', function() {
      this.someFn = function() {
        alert('this is working');
      };
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When we use like this, we are just using service as a middle man right? I want a two way communication between these directives. So, if one button is clicked on directive1, some action should happen on directive2 and vice versa. So, if we are using a service, how do we do that?

Comment: Just saw your comment.  Again, it depends on exactly what you're doing.  Say you want directive1 (D1) to make a change to some value that directive2 (D2) picks up.  One example, would be to have D1 call a function on the service to change some value, while D2 has a $watch set on one of the service's properties.  Check out this blog post on using the 3 variations of $watch.  http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2566-Scope-watch-vs-watchCollection-In-AngularJS.htm  You could use the same method to have D2 call a function when the value is changed on the service.

Comment: Here is an updated plunker with an example using an array.  http://plnkr.co/edit/I2TvvV

Answer (score 1):

You should use `require` when your directives are **related**: like an accordion and accordion items.

To communicate between scopes, you should try $on, $emit, $broadcast. In your case, you need to inject rootScope into your directive, and broadcast an event from rootScope:

```
.directive('searchResultHeader', 

    function($rootScope) { //inject rootScope
      return {
        replace: true,
        template: '<button>clickme</button>',
        link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
          $elem.on('click', function() {
            $rootScope.$broadcast("someEvent"); //broadcast an event to all child scopes.
          });
        }
      };
    }
  );
```

**Any scopes** interested in the event can subscribe to it using $on:

```
function($scope) {
      $scope.$on("someEvent", function() { 
          alert('this is working');
      });
    }
```

Using events is a way to create **decoupled systems**.

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/mhomcZ?p=preview)

Comment: Yes. we can use like this. But, is this a good approach? I think, angular is not suggesting to use broadcast or emit too much, right?

Comment: @jintoppy: There are 2 solutions to this problem: using events and using services. Which to use depends on our application. We use services when we have some `shared` properties between scopes => when another scope modifies these `shared` properties, all the other scopes notice the changes. In other cases, we use events. I don't think angular is not suggesting to use broadcast or emit too much, it should depend on the context.

Comment: @jintoppy: If your directives don't have anything to shared. I would go with using events to create a more decoupled system.

Comment: I personally use events *very* sparingly and only in very specific situations.  For example, the only event used in the application I'm currently working on is to notify the rest of the application that there has been a configuration change, so each interested piece can update its own configuration.

Comment: @Craig Squire: in fact, event-driven is very useful. It's a way to create decoupled systems as you components `do not have to directly depend` on other components.

Comment: @KhanhTO I don't disagree that they are useful, but if they are your primary solution to creating loosely coupled components there is a high likelihood you will end up with spaghetti code.